# How do you search for a RTW ticket on ITA Matrix?

Tags: around-the-world, ita-matrix

Is it possible to search ITA Matrix for a RTW ticket offered by the three major alliances?

Most specifically, assume that you have an itinerary that contains flights that follow the rules of the particular RTW ticket, is it possible to enter the flights into ITA Matrix and determinate availability of flights on the given days that could be booked?

For example, given the booking codes published by Skyteam and listed at https://www.skyteam.com/en/business-solutions/travel-agents/round-the-world-planner/round-the-world-booking-classes, what would I need to add to the routing and/or extension codes at ITA Matrix to get a RTW fare?

For the avoidance of doubt, I am not looking for "hacker" fares or fares offered by travel agents outside the airline alliances.

Comment: Someone else may correct me, but I don't _think_ ITA Matrix will price RTW fares at all: those are usually their own category of fares and don't work like normal fare rules. ITA Matrix may be a useful tool to find specific segments to use in your RTW booking, such as flights with availability in particular fare classes or flights that don't exceed a certain number of miles, and to see the taxes and surcharges that apply to particular flights.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe ITA Matrix can do this. The rules are simply too complicated. Even the actual search engines seem to choke at it at the moment since there are so many restrictions in place that change frequently.

I found that 3rd party providers, such as https://www.airtreks.com/ (just an example, no product recommendation applied) probably are your best shot at the moment.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, alas. "assume that you have an itinerary that contains flights that follow the rules of the particular RTW ticket", and "fares offered by travel agents outside the airline alliances" excludes Airtreks.

Comment: Sometimes 'no' is a valid answer.